# Cannot add object to array in Facebook SDK block

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook iOS SDK:

```
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    int i = 0;   
        jsonNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < [jsonData count]; i++){
        numberOfObjects=numberOfObjects+1;
        NSLog(@"FB ID = %@",[[jsonData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"fbID"]);
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[[jsonData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"fbID"]]
                                     parameters:nil
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(
                                                  FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error
                                                  ) {
                                  [jsonNames addObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"]];
                                  NSLog(@"anything %@",[result objectForKey:@"name"]);
                              }];
    }

    NSLog(@"JSON NAMES ARRY = %@",jsonNames);
        nearbyTV.dataSource = self;
        nearbyTV.delegate = self;
        [nearbyTV reloadData];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.6
                         animations:^{
                             nearbyTV.hidden=NO;
                         }];
    });
});
```

What is really frustrating is I cannot add the names to this array `jsonnames`, but I can long them right below with `NSLog`. What is wrong here? I try to initialise the array before this and it is an `NSMutableArray` I even try to add `__block` before it with no difference. Why can't I add the object to the array??? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Post the code that alloc/inits the jsonNames array. in your completion block, log the entire jsonNames array. My guess is that at the time the block fires, jsonNames is nil.

Comment: updated the code @DuncanC I really appreciate your response. I don't think that is the case however because I add the object `hi` to the array right before the block. (which actually prevents it from crashing b/c it would be empty, obviously)

Comment: Adding something to a nil array will not crash in Objective-C. It's legal to send messages to nil. Post the header where you define jsonNames.